# Size issue with body of Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm with text/html

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I am developing an outlook add-in for Mac OS using OfficeJs API.
As per the requirement, I am using `Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm()` method to open an Appointment window programmatically, on the click of the button.

```
Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm(
{
    location: '{Location}',
    subject: '{subject}',
    body: '{some large text}'
});
```

If the `body` text is 255 characters or less, then the appointment window gets opened with the pre-populated body, subject, and location. But if the body text exceeds that size, no appointment window is opened.

I know that there is a limit of 32KB for the appointment form's `body` but my text is not more than that. (I have confirmed it on a character to KB converter).

If I add a subject and the text of Subject exceeds more than 255 characters (specified in API documentation), It gives an exception.

But for the body, it gives no exception to characters more than 255 and does not open new Appointment window.

IMPORTANT UPDATE: As this is office add-in and it works on Windows platform as well. It works as expected for Windows and the text renders perfectly. So, it seems it is a bug for Mac!

Link of Demo Code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NoWfxd8p3kYQ1AkRXtE0DS4NmyN4PmiY/view

Comment: Why downvote, please add the reason for downvoting.  This is a real problem and I am seeking for a solution.

Comment: Are you sure this is about size of the `body`? Did you escape the string which you pass into JSON? You have it in double quotes, so you would need to escape double quotes of the string you assign to the body. As you mention doc says it is limited to 32K.

Comment: Yes, I have used single quotes in place of double quotes and problem still persists.

Comment: Well, in this case somebody from Microsoft Office dev team may need to step up.Sorry, cannot help further.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are encountering this issue in Outlook Web and not Outlook Desktop? And which browser is this reproducing in?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am facing this issue in Outlook Desktop.

Comment: Can you tell us which version of Outlook Desktop you are using, and the build number?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Outlook for Mac
Version 16.11 (180311)
License: Office 365 Subscription

Comment: Can I please get some help on this?

Comment: Adding a full demo code for the reference, if anyone want to look into the issue - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NoWfxd8p3kYQ1AkRXtE0DS4NmyN4PmiY/view

Comment: Thanks for raising it. We are working on the fix for Mac outlook. Will check-in ASAP and update the thread.

Comment: Thanks @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility for the confirmation.

Comment: Hi @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility, can I please get some update till when it will be fixed?

Comment: Hi, This has been fixed and got checked in. Please use build version > 180518

Comment: Thanks, @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility, I am checking and will update you soon.

Comment: Hi,
If you are suggesting about outlook build version. I have upgraded to latest outlook build and still, I can see this bug. Please update me the correct way to get the fix.

Previous version: Microsoft Outlook for Mac Version 16.11 (180311) License: Office 365 Subscription
Current version: Microsoft Outlook for Mac Version 16.13.1 (180523) License: Office 365 Subscription

Comment: @KanakSony, please use the latest insider fast build and check if the issue still exists. Instructions to be part of insider fast is here: https://products.office.com/en-in/office-insider?tab=Mac